# How to support Bluetooth for both Android 1.x and 2.x at the same time?

Tags: android

I can access the Android bluetooth api via reflection in Android 1.x and I can also access bluetooth api 2.x using the build in Android class but I can't support both at the same time in my App. Like having the reflection to use the old bluetooth api to support 1.x and at the sametime using the new api for 2.0+ with a 2.0 Android build.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the methods in Build.VERSION (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)